# Restful webservices(Apache wink+Guice+openjpa)

Tags: guice-3

I would like to use the following technologies to develop restful webservice.

Apache wink+Guice3+openjpa. I dont know how to use guice with wink and openjpa. could you please explain.

Answer (score 3):

I can't help you with OpenJPA, but I just now figured out how to use `Guice` with `Wink`. First of all, you do not need to use Guice's `guice-servlet` JAR as you would with a plain webapp. Just set up your webapp to use Wink as you normally would, then follow these steps.

1. Replace the `wink-server` JAR with the `wink-guice-server` JAR (available from the same source).
2. Change the `servlet-class` in your `web.xml` file from

   > org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet

   to

   > org.apache.wink.**guice.**server.internal.servlet.**Guice**RestServlet
3. Also in `web.xml`, add this snippet to Wink's `<servlet-class>` element:

   ```
   <init-param>
       <param-name>deploymentConfiguration</param-name>
       <param-value>com.yourco.yourproj.DeploymentConfiguration</param-value>
   </init-param>
   ```
4. Finally, create a new Wink `DeploymentConfiguration` class, which I call here `com.yourco.yourproj.DeploymentConfiguration`.

   ```
   package com.yourco.yourproj;

   import com.google.inject.Module;
   import org.apache.wink.guice.server.internal.GuiceDeploymentConfiguration;
   import org.apache.wink.guice.server.internal.lifecycle.WinkGuiceModule;

   public class DeploymentConfiguration extends GuiceDeploymentConfiguration {
       @Override
       public Module[] createModules() {
           return new Module[] { new WinkGuiceModule(), new YourModule() };
       }
   }
   ```

   `YourModule` is just a normal Guice module.